# Tying in public purchase records

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a list of purchases for work. Currently, what we're doing is tracing product orders based on what our customers have said they've bought. For instance, Steve says he has bought iPhones on the 3rd Jan 2022, the 15th Dec 2021 and the 1st of Nov 2021.

What I'm currently doing is a very arduous task - three separate queries, extracting them all, then removing duplicates in Excel to then analyze the account ID's that have bought on those three dates.

This in of itself takes time, but also, some customers buy 5, 7, 10 products etc so it can become quite difficult.

```
select tt.order_time, tt.from, tt.to, tt.value/1e9, tt.orderID
from transactiontable tt
where right(tt.data::varchar,8) = '9092fcb5' 
and left(tt.data::varchar, 10) in ('\xfb3bdb41', '\x7ff36ab5') 
and tt.contract_address = '\9092fcb5'
and tt.order_time between '2022-05-09 00:00' and '2022-05-09 23:59'
```

Does anyone have any help on how I can essentially take X number of queries and then only show me the distanct "from" addresses for each overall query?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is way too specific .. We're going to need a lot more information, and a  lot less explanation ..  1) Start with the data structure, so we can duplicate your dataset.  2 What is your intended result?  3) What have you tried do achieve this result?  4) Where do you believe the problem lies?  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi Zak

Currently if I want to trace whether people have actually bought our products I need to extract X sets of data and then de-dupe them to identify customers that bought on date A, B and C.

My intended result is to extract a list of all customers who fulfill the criteria of having bought on dates A, B and C.

The above SQL are the fields I want to extract & the table naming structure. I have to repeat that three times, extract the results and then whittle them down. I'm asking for a solution where I can have the distinct "from"  (customers) that fulfill all three criteria. Thanks.

Comment: I solved it buy writing multiple queries and using the "Intersect" operator.